# How to remove snakes from a plain?

Tags: society, religion

There is an African plain, there are trees, grasses, some seasonal rivers/lakes, and snakes.

Upon the plain lives a society of tribesmen (think along the lines of the [Maasai Mara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maasai_Mara) people)

[image]
[This image used with permission: Source (Alamy)](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/masai-mara-tribe.html)

These tribes love life, but hate snakes - they are the embodiment of the evil spirits, they cannot be eaten, they also cannot be killed (life is more treasured than evil is hated).

Of course, there's plenty of snakes around.

So the question (obviously) is how can the tribesmen get the snakes off the plain?

Comment: You mean other than picking them up, putting them in a basket and turn them into handbags later? Well. Go and breed some predators that do not have the same religious problems with turning them into lunch. You can still turn the leftovers into handbags afterwards.

Comment: Came here specifically to edit your poor spelling, was not disappointed.

Comment: @Burki evil, living baskets made of snakes?

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ yes. Evil and living as long as they are being fed regularly. Which, imho, will not happen at all. So soon you will have a basket full of not-so-evil and not-so-living handbag material.

Comment: @Burki Well, I guess that's a deterrence for pick-pockets...

Comment: Does St. Patrick do requests?

Comment: "How to remove snakes from a plain"... hmmm... have you considered asking Samuel L. Jackson for help? I hear he's had enough of these monkey-flying snakes on this monday-friday plain.

Comment: @Burki: it's difficult to remember that the objective was to rid the plain of snakes when you find yourself up to your a** in mongooses.

Comment: @Z.Schroeder: Exactly. How is "Get Samuel L. Jackson" not the top answer already?

Comment: Serious question: Do you have rights to replicate that photo? If you do, please edit the question to note that you have rights to the photo. If you do not, please delete the photo. Display in a public forum does not count under fair use when you take the entire work -- i.e., a whole photo.

Comment: I followed the citation. I expanded the text to make it explicit that this image is used with permission. For those who are interested, here's Getty Images permission page: http://www.gettyimages.com/unreleased-imagery WorldBuilding does clearly fall under allowed use.

Comment: I expected the OP to be Samuel l.

Comment: Every people in the world is afraid of snakes, but can't and shouldn't destroy them. We don't usually like rats as well, and snakes control rats populations. As you see, everything has a good and a bad side. Westerners think they should "correct" Nature, and that's the basis for your impossible question, and also for our destruction of the Environment.

Comment: @Rodrigo - There's nothing "impossible" about this question.  "Impossible" doesn't relate to superstition or religion.  If Hindus can hold cows as being sacred, why can't these tribes hold snakes as being the opposite.  In terms of old Christianity, the snake is the devil.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ yes, you're right. That's why Christians (old and present) are the #1 in Environmental Destruction in the world. Now, if these tribesmen actually succeed in eliminating all the snakes, I can only imagine the number of ecological problems they would have right after.

Comment: Nuke them from space.  Its the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Just ask Moses

From [Artapansus of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artapanus_of_Alexandria) in his History of the Jews:

> Jealousy of Moses' excellent qualities induced Chenephres to send him
>   with unskilled troops on a military expedition to Ethiopia, where he
>   won great victories. After having built the city of Hermopolis, he
>   taught the people the value of the ibis as a protection against the
>   serpents, making the bird the sacred guardian spirit of the city...

## Behold, your savior

[image]

## Your people worship the Ibis

Not only are [Sacred Ibis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_sacred_ibis)' great for keeping around and eating snakes, they are also native to the same plains that the Masai Mara live on, and they are [easy to worship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoth) too!

[image]

Comment: I'm looking at the Wikipedia entry for Ibis, and I see these references, except that it does not say that the Ibis eats snakes...?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibis

Comment: @Mikey There is no room for your so-called 'facts' here. Bow before the almighty Ibis-God, without whose grace, a serpent would be surely sinking its fangs into your heels right now! Bow!

Comment: well, it got a +1 anyway.  What about a mongoose?

Comment: I have a strong desire to post "a song about birds" from youtube here, but it's rather NSFW so I won't...

Comment: How in the world does this have so many upvotes?

Comment: @sgroves it properly recognizes our saviors, the sacred ibis. Hail.

Comment: @mikey the Wikipedia article for the general Ibis bird doesn't mention the snake eating, but there are other sites that mention it, like http://bestiary.ca/beasts/beast342.htm, https://animalcorner.co.uk/animals/sacred-ibis-bird/, and many of the individual Wikipedia pages on birds commonly taxonomized as ibis mention snakes being part of the diet.

Comment: @kingledion This must be a post-fact non-fake-news article ;)

Comment: @Mikey, [will this do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GELHhAo0wAA)

Comment: Same thing you do when there are snakes on a normal plane, call security.

Answer (score 20):

Why do you have snakes on the plain in the first place?  Rodents!  So you need to find a way to control the rodent populations.  If the snakes have nothing to eat, they won't hang about in large numbers.

Introduce species that will eliminate the rodents and the snakes won't have prey.  This is why Bast was an Egyptian Goddess.  She represented cats, which kept critters out of the grain cribs.  Also weasels and ferrets and mongoose might help.  The mongoose will also eat the snakes as well.  Then the whole killing snakes becomes a circle of life thing.

Mammals are going to have an advantage in that they are not as affected by cold.

In a culture like you describe, though, I would think the snake might at least be respected because it does help control the rodent population without endangering the food supply.  So Sam L Jackson may not be necessary after all.

Comment: Introduce a bunch of owls a la Futurama.

Comment: That wouldn't be a bad idea.  Plenty of raptor birds eat snakes, in addition to eating what the snakes are there to eat, rodents

Comment: @mbomb007 - well, I was about to point out that owls roost in trees (which they do) and trees seem kinda scarce, but then I remembered that the [Burrowing Owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrowing_owl) nests in, well, burrows. Or perhaps you could invent a Burroing Owl which nests on the backs of plains donkeys. Or the completely unknown Excavating Owl which is a well-known tool-using animal, preferring backhoes, bulldozers, front-end loaders, and the like. Or the HIGHLY dangerous Glow-In-The-Dark Ground Zero Owl, known for its use of practical physics when digging a new nest-hole.

Comment: There's a Facebook app called MouseHunt. Maybe the owls invented it.

Comment: Next question, how to get rid of your owl infestation.

Comment: You know what else eats rodents? Ibis. They're an all in one solution!

Comment: quite true  The Ibis is a very good candidate.

Comment: @mbomb007 owls are pests, though.  (And golden marmosets...)

Answer (score 5):

> Kookaburra roams through the plains with glee, eating all the snakes
>   with a grin is he, laugh, Kookaburra laugh, Kookaburra full your stomach
>   must be.

The humble Kookaburra! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kookaburra
A less well known Australian bird who loves to eat snakes and small rodents (solves two suspected problems here!!)

My only problem would be that they would usually nest in a tree, so if there are no suitable trees around, we may have to make a hybrid kingfisher-kookaburra breed which would use the habitat of the kingfisher which is small holes in sand-mounds.

Comment: Hmm - I've just noticed that the snakes cannot be killed. Does being eaten by another animal count?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, it's a Circle of Life thing.  Animals can't be chastised for not respecting religion.

Comment: Only one problem with kookaburras: the awful noise they make. I think you may prefer snakes.

Comment: Awful? @redsonja? Have you ever woken up to the beautiful sound of a kookaburra? Ya kidding me!

Comment: @RedSonja Kookaburras are magnificent! Their sound is one of the most beautiful in nature.

Comment: There goes the local ecology. If a plain supports that many snakes, then getting rid of them will unleash the Mother and Father of vermin plagues. Don't say you weren't warned.

Comment: @a4android hahahahahahahahahahahahahaha

Comment: @RedSonja My point exactly.

Comment: Or domesticate/breed/release [secretary birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretarybird) which are native to Africa.  The problem is when there are only a few snakes left in an area, the birds will run out of food or turn to other prey species, so you'll never eliminate the snakes completely.  An army of semi-domesticated metre-high birds would be cool though.

Comment: @ChrisH Secretary Bird???? Is that pronounced 'Ibis'?

Comment: @kingledion, no, they're not closely related. The secretary bird (raptor) is considerably taller than even a large species of ibis (wader). It's like an eagle on stilts, with a beak to match, and stalks impressively rather than flying.

Answer (score 1):

### Do what any human does and kill them

Look at human history, you can likely easily name 5 animals off the top of your head that humanity has hunted to extinction. Unless the animals mass breeds like insects, early man has always had dominion over animal life.

If these people truly hated and despised the snakes, to the point that they saw it their religious duty to god to kill them, the snakes wouldn't stand a chance. Humans always win.

Comment: Yes, but we don't really want to kill the snakes.  It's a sin.  And the tribesmen don't really want to meet those snakes in the afterlife.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ Then I am doubting the feasibility of this, they have no way of catching them, because of their tech level and they can't kill them? It seems like the snakes might be here to stay

Comment: That didn't stop the giraffe from answering....

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ giraffes are myths

Comment: Why can't they practice catch and release? with a forked stick and a basket snake catching isn't much harder than snake killing, if you have the free time to play with things instead of eating them.

Comment: That would work. Catch the snakes and export them to places where owning a poisonous serpent is KEWL! You get rid of your snake problem AND you wipe out an entire generation of foreign kids who are way too much into The Latest Thing. Hmmm...a snake with every cell phone..? ****blink-blink**** ***NAAAAAAHHHHHH!!!!***

Comment: There are plenty of animals that humanity have hunted to extinction, but I can name plenty of animals that we would have *loved* to hunted to extinction, but have failed to:  mice (*Mus musculus*), rats (*Rattus norvegicus*), rabbits (*Oryctolagus cuniculus*), etc.  It helps to be small, fast, and fast breeding.

Comment: @BobJarvis Ireland needs more snakes...